# In "mongosh", how do I delete all databases without deleting the typical "admin", "config", or "local" databases?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongo-shell

**What am I trying to do?**

I wrote a script called `deleteDatabases.js` and it's supposed to delete all databases (besides "admin", "config", or "local") when inside `mongosh`. I do not have access to `mongo`, only `mongosh`.

**What is the code that currently tries to do that?**

`deleteDatabases.js`

```js
Mongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(x) {
  if (['admin', 'config', 'local'].indexOf(x) < 0) {
    Mongo().getDB(x).dropDatabase();
  }
})
```

Inside `mongosh`:

```sh
$ mongosh
...
Using MongoDB: 4.4.1
Using Mongosh Beta: 0.4.0
> show dbs
admin 184 kB
config 36.9 kB
database1 283 kB
database2 420 kB
database3 1337 kB
local 90.1 kB
> .load /deleteDatabases.js

... (Code from deleteDatabases.js) ...

TypeError: (intermediate value).getDBNames is not a function
```

Before what I did to successfully delete these databases was:

```sh
> db = db.getSiblingDB("database1")
database1
> db.dropDatabase()
{ ok: 1, dropped: 'database1' }
# Repeat for each database I want deleted.
```

**What do I expect the result to be?**

I expect all the databases to be deleted besides "admin", "config", or "local".

**What is the actual result?**

As above, there's a `TypeError`.

**What I think the problem could be?**

1. The version of `mongosh` I'm using is out of date and does not have those methods implemented yet or at all.
2. My `.js` file is implemented incorrectly.

Was wondering if there was an alternative where I still use `mongosh` unless I have to use something else.

EDIT:

`deleteDatabases.js`

```js
db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ).databases.
  map(database => database.name).
  filter(name => ["admin", "config", "local"].indexOf(name) == -1).
  forEach(function(name){db.getSiblingDB(name).dropDatabase()})
```

This is the fix that I'm using, but would love the `.map()` to work so I can see an output after running the command as spoken by Joe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [listDatabases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/) admin command, `map` to get just the database name, and `filter` to eliminate the ones you don't want:

```
db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases.
   map(d => d.name).
   filter(n => ["admin", "config", "local"].indexOf(n) == -1 ).
   map(n => db.getSiblingDB(n).dropDatabase())
```

Note that if you use `map` instead of `forEach` you will get back a confirmation of which databases were dropped successfully, like

```
[
  { ok: 1, dropped: 'test' },
  { ok: 1, dropped: 'test1' },
  { ok: 1, dropped: 'test2' }
]
```

Comment: I have tried your code and received this error: `MongoshInvalidInputError: Cannot pass a function that calls a Mongosh API method as an argument` Wondering if there's possibly something I'm missing.

Comment: I alleviated the error in two different areas as so in my "EDIT" above. It works but would like to get the `.map()` to work for the last part of the script in order to output the databases drop confirmation.

Comment: Might be a version thing?  I'm using mongosh 0.12.0, when I copy-paste that code it gives the output just like shown.

Comment: It definitely is a version thing, you are correct. Thanks for the help!